# SqlAlchemy sort by first record in relationship column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Need a bit of help concerning relationships and filtering.  Given the following models, how can I sort the Project's Milestones by the Milestone.active_date?

After trying this, I understand I can't do this with a property.  I've tried and the error i get that its not a mappable table makes sense. So what's the best/correct way to perform this?

I've looked into hybrid_property and joins but I can't seem to get this working.  I'm quite rusty on databases and haven't done much with ORM's before so a detailed explanation would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

BW

```
class MilestoneType(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'MilestoneType'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    icon_name = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class Milestone(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Milestone'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    milestone_type_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(MilestoneType.id))
    milestone_type = db.relationship("MilestoneType")
    milestone_dates = db.relationship("MilestoneDate", order_by="MilestoneDate.datestamp", lazy="dynamic")
    notes = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Project.id'), nullable=False)
    project = db.relationship("Project")

    @property
    def active_date(self):
        return self.milestone_dates.first()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ' (Type: ' + str(self.milestone_type) + ')'


class MilestoneDate(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'MilestoneDate'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    milestone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Milestone.id'), nullable=False)
    milestone = db.relationship("Milestone")
    datestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    notes = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.datestamp)


class Project(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Project'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.String(8), nullable=False)
    responsible = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Customer.id))
    customer = db.relationship("Customer")
    project_type_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(ProjectType.id))
    project_type = db.relationship("ProjectType")
    product_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Product.id))
    product = db.relationship("Product")
    site_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Site.id))
    site = db.relationship("Site")
    milestones = db.relationship("Milestone", lazy="dynamic")

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.customer) + " - " + str(self.name) + '(' + str(self.product) + ')'
```

Comment: What did you try with a hybrid prop? A hybrid property that evaluates to a scalar subquery in expression context is one way to solve this. A traditional property on Project instead of a relationship attribute returning a more complex query another. What DB are you using?

Comment: How do you sort the data in your query?

Comment: Hey.  Thanks.  I've used relational databases for a long time but with what I imagine are pretty basic implementation so I don't fully understand your comment without doing a bit of reading but I will look into the hybrid property.  The milestone date data is sorted by a datetime stamp and I want to sort the milestones by the "active date" which is the nearest date of the milestone date set.

Comment: The DB you are using may direct the answer, so please provide that information.

Comment: I am using SQLite for now - in development.  I am not tied to anything for production and I may just keep it as SQLite as its going to be a small-scale tool.